# Table with fixed and variable width for MS Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

I'm trying to make a signature that works cross-platform. Given that I will be sending emails to people with outlook, I want it to appear right in Outlook too.

What I want to do is move the text I type to the right so it aligns properly with the image below.

I can make it work perfectly in my own mail client, which is Thunderbird, and view it in all browsers okay too, but getting it to work in outlook seems a problem.

Using a div and CSS seems to be out of the question, outlook simply ignores it and it vanishes.

When I use a table, outlook does seem to honor it, but getting both a fixed and variable width cell that behave seems to be a problem.

I tried the following html code:

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="64"><br></td>
    <td><font face="Arial" size="2">
        <br><br>Yours Sincerely,<br><br></font>
    </font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <img alt="" src="file:///X:/image.png" height="168" width="681">
    </td>
</tr>
```

This works everywhere, except outlook. Does anyone know a way to fix this, or a different method I could use that will work? I'd like to prevent going for 2 fixed width columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-left: 64px;"><font face="Arial" size="2">
        <br><br>Yours Sincerely,<br><br></font>
    </font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img alt="" src="file:///X:/image.png" height="168" width="681">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It's not true that you can't use CSS for Outlook. It only has to be inline and only a few things work. One of them is Padding. This should space your text away from the left side and also work in Outlook.

Also you don't need the colespan, since a row is fitted to the contend and is expanding past other rows, if not specified.

Comment: I tried your approach with a DIV and it was completely removed by outlook. I'll give it a try with a TD and see what happens. Thanks. :)

Comment: Yes, Outlook removes Div's. For the futur: Here is a List with what works where in different Mail Clients: [CampaignMonitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Comment: Yes, I had found that page myself. It lists table-layout as a supported CSS tag, yet it doesn't work. So I've written that down as not reliable. I still have to test this though. Don't worry I hope to do that soon, its just that I recently left at my job where we used outlook and I currently don't have a test setup. I have to install outlook locally to be able to test this, but I want to setup a Virtual Machine for that. Long story short, it takes time. xD I will definitely report back to you though.

Comment: Hi, I would love to help you! I got a Outlook 2010 Testing Client wich I use to test my Mails. Is there a Private Message Feature on this Site so I could send you some information privately?

Comment: It should be possible to turn this into a chat, but I'm not sure how private it is. But I got Outlook 2013 installed and I plan to work on this today. If all goes well I will have an answer in a few hours.

Comment: Okay, that was so much quicker than I thought. I tested it and it works perfectly. I used Outlook 2013, but I'm pretty sure that it will work in 2010, 2013 and 2016 which are the 3 versions I'm targetting. Thanks! bounty awarded. :)